# .NET Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client invalid cast of date

Tags: .net, oracle

I am converting some old VBScripts to .NET console apps. This SQL works just fine in the VBScript, as well as Oracle SQL Developer, and even in MS Access using ODBC. But when debugging my console app targeting .NET framework 4.7 and using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess NuGet package version 21.12.0, I get an exception "Specified cast is not valid.". I have narrowed the problem down to a date problem. In my SELECT I am subtracting a date from CURRENT_DATE to calculate how old a record is.
`CURRENT_DATE - PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.MODIFY_DATE_TIME AS days`.
CURRENT_DATE is a built-in Oracle function, and I have verified that MODIFY_DATE_TIME is of Oracle data type DATE.

I am fairly new to Oracle and the ManagedDataAccess Client, and am unsure of how to deal with this issue since this works everywhere else I've tried it.

````
        Dim dataTable As New DataTable
       
            Using oracleConnection As New OracleConnection(ProdConnectionString)
                Dim oracleCommand As OracleCommand = oracleConnection.CreateCommand()
                oracleCommand.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT
                                                CURRENT_DATE - PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.MODIFY_DATE_TIME AS days,
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.SEQUENCE_NBR,
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.FORM_NAME,
                                                FUNCTION.DESCRIPTION,
                                                USER_LIST.LAST_NAME,
                                                USER_LIST.FIRST_NAME,
                                                USER_LIST.USERID,
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.INITIATED_BY,
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_PROJECT.DESCRIPTION Project,
                                                cnt.C - 1 AS C,
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.STATUS
                                            FROM
                                                 ((((PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG 
                                            LEFT JOIN 
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_PROJECT ON PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.PROJECT_CD = PROGRAM_CHANGE_PROJECT.PROJECT_CD) 
                                            LEFT JOIN 
                                                FUNCTION ON PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.FORM_NAME = FUNCTION.FUNCTION_NAME) 
                                            INNER JOIN 
                                                USER_LIST ON PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.REQUEST_BY = USER_LIST.USERID)
                                            INNER JOIN 
                                                (SELECT Count(PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.SEQUENCE_NBR) C, 
                                                    PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.FORM_NAME
                                                FROM 
                                                    PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG 
                                                WHERE 
                                                    PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.STATUS IN ('OPEN','TEST','QUES') 
                                                GROUP BY 
                                                    PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.FORM_NAME) cnt ON PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.FORM_NAME = cnt.FORM_NAME) 
                                            INNER JOIN 
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_NOTES ON PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.SEQUENCE_NBR = PROGRAM_CHANGE_NOTES.SEQUENCE_NBR
                                            GROUP BY 
                                                current_date-PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.MODIFY_DATE_TIME, 
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.SEQUENCE_NBR, 
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.FORM_NAME, 
                                                FUNCTION.DESCRIPTION, 
                                                USER_LIST.LAST_NAME, 
                                                USER_LIST.FIRST_NAME, 
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.INITIATED_BY, 
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_PROJECT.DESCRIPTION, 
                                                cnt.C, 
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.STATUS, 
                                                USER_LIST.USERID
                                            HAVING 
                                                PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.STATUS IN ('TEST', 'QUES') 
                                            ORDER BY 
                                                days DESC"
        
                oracleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                 Try
                    oracleConnection.Open()
                    Dim oracleDataAdapter As New OracleDataAdapter(oracleCommand)
                    oracleDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)
                    oracleConnection.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    'WriteLog(ex)
                End Try

            End Using

            Return dataTable

    End Function```
````

Comment: I imagine the problem is in your fetch of the data, possibly just having the columns in the wrong order (so you're trying to fetch a date value, say, but the corresponding column in the result set is a number). It would help if you showed your code and a [mre].

Comment: OK, so is the error actually coming from that code (it isn't in the query itself, as it isn't an ORA- error; plus the same query works elsewhere), and if so from which line; or is it when you access data from dataTable? Your query doesn't appear to return any dates, so what/where is your code casting? (As an aside, and irrelevant to this issue, why do you have a `group by` clause with no aggregation - maybe that should have been removed when you added `distinct`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a work-around.

The error was coming from the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess NuGet package.
The "GetDecimal" in the stack trace clued me in...

[image: Exception Data]

The query returns a decimal in OracleSQLDeveloper.

[image: SQL Developer Result]

So I added a ROUND function to the query in my .NET app and it now returns a DataTable without throwing an exception.
`ROUND(CURRENT_DATE - PROGRAM_CHANGE_LOG.MODIFY_DATE_TIME) AS days,`

[image: Returned DataTable]

Thanks for your comments. Again new to Oracle and this was not my query, it has been in use in the VBScript for many years.

Comment: If you are counting complete days then you probably want FLOOR (or TRUNC) rather than ROUND. Possibly worth checking how the old VBScript - whether it silently rounded or truncated by default, or did something else, and whether it was right...